# TS: Typing higher order function with rest params ...args

Tags: typescript, args, spread-syntax

I wrote a little helper function in Typescript but I am getting the error message `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)`

```
export type TDemethodise = (f: Function) => (...args: any[]) => void

export const demethodise: TDemethodise = (fn) => (...args): void => fn.bind(...args);
```

I am very unsure about typing this. Is it possible to type this without heavily altering the function?

Answer (score 0):

`Function.bind()` takes a `thisArg` as its first argument. It is not entirely clear from your code what you would expect `this` to be bound to in the "demethodized" function, but e.g. binding it to itself `fn.bind(fn, ...args)` would work.